# Does this scroll effect have a name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm looking to find the name of this scrolling effect.

As you scroll, the text on the screen changes, as if you were going through a slideshow. [The gif is from this website](https://app.optimism.io/announcement).

I have an idea of how to implement it, but would prefer to use some js library (ideally for react, but not required) that already implements it. Does anyone have an idea of the name, or some library that has it? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: this link might be useful. https://greensock.com/gsap/

Comment: Looks like just parallax scrolling to me. I've used [react-scroll-parallax](https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/intro) before.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added an edit. I think it's slightly different from parallax. I'm interested in the text changing as you scroll, as if you were going through a slideshow. However, the position of the text does not follow the scrollbar linearly. It's as if there were breaking point where it stops, then when you beyond a certain threshold, then it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just called scroll-linked animations.

Typically for website animations, you would want to use CSS keyframes, as it is more performant than using javascript. Though you can always trigger CSS keyframe animations with javascript, and tie it to scroll events to create the above effect.